# Multi-threaded managed application that calls native code

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have a service that's using ASP WebApi. Each http request translates to a thread that needs to do some data manipulation (possibly changing the data). The API layer is written in C# and the data manipulation is written in C++. The C# layer calls the native library and supplies a pointer to some managed buffer.

Couple of questions:

1. How can I make sure there are no races? is `std::mutex` in the native library enough in this case? (do managed threads map to native threads? will they share the same `std::mutex`?)
2. How can I make sure that the GC doesn't release the pointer to the managed buffer while the native library is manipulating it?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what have you tried so far? Why do you want the buffer to be managed? Are both the C# and C++ side going to manipulate that buffer? Is the buffer per-request, or shared? What's in the buffer?

Comment: @Luaan We're trying to process a lot of data efficiently as possible. That's why we decided to process it in C++. The buffer is managed because I prefer to use as much C# as possible. Only C++ manipulates the data. The buffer holds telemetry data sent to us by our application

Comment: Okay... but that means you'll only be working with the buffer when you call the C++ interop method from C#, right? So you can handle e.g. locking in the C# level, right? It might even make the `fixed` approach below work well enough, if you don't keep the `fixed` reference for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you need a *shared* buffer? If the buffer is only ever used on one thread, you save yourself a lot of trouble. Managed threads do not map to native threads 1:1, but I'm not sure if that has any effect on your scenario.
2. You need to fix the buffer, and keep it fixed the whole time the native code has a pointer to it - releasing is the least of your worries, the .NET memory is moved around all the time. This is done using the `fixed` block.

Fixing managed memory:

```
byte[] theBuffer = new byte[256];
fixed (byte* ptr = &theBuffer[0])
{
   // The pointer is now fixed - the GC is prohibited from moving the memory
   TheNativeFunction(ptr);
}
// Unfixed again
```

However, note that prohibiting the GC from moving memory around can cause you quite a bit of trouble - it can prevent heap compaction altogether in a high-throughput server, for example.

If you don't need to work with the memory in the managed environment, you can simply allocate unmanaged memory for the task, such as by using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

Comment: thanks. 1. Unfortunately, this has to be a shared buffer (we're low on memory and cannot afford to copy it around 2. Can wrl::ComPtr<> help here by managing the ref count?

Comment: @Shmoopy I don't see how it could. It's actually pretty easy to handle memory references and pointers safely in C# - for example, you could derive a type from the `SafeBuffer` class; it will provide you with a safe reference to unmanaged memory you can work with relatively easily. But it's hard to say anything more specific without knowing more about your whole scenario.